# store data from database from call back

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback

I am working on node js project, I am using ipstack to get user data from IP. can't understand how to get data from callback function and insert it into my database.

here is my code

```
const ipstack = require('ipstack');

const ip = '103.195.74.60';
ipstack(ip, process.env.IPSTACK, (err, response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

insert query here

```
// create user
await User.create({
    fullName,
    phone,
    email,
    nikeName,
    ip,
    city (come from ip),
    zip (come from ip),
    browser,
    device,
});
```

Comment: anyone here to help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just need to make the database traction exactly  where you are using the `console.log` call, as following:

const ipstack = require("ipstack");

```
const ip = "103.195.74.60";
ipstack(ip, process.env.IPSTACK, (err, response) => {
  // First of all you need to check if there is error
  if (err){
    // handle error  hreer, you might need to use `return`
    // at some point to not execute the below code, alternatively 
    // you could just wrap it in `else`
               }
    console.log(response); // your orginal `console.log` call

  //your  database transaction ca be done here,
  // create user
  
            await User.create({
                fullName,
                phone,
                email,
                nikeName,
                ip,
                response.city // need to look in documentation 
                response.zip // or explore the response object terminal 
                browser,
                device,
            })
            
});
```

The part of code where I access the keys of response is speculation, you just need to look for documentation if exists for the `ipstack` package, or just by exploring the schema `response` given you are `console.log`.

Lastly, I would suggest using the [official documentation](https://ipstack.com/documentation) given the  [`lipstick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipstack) is not really maintained the last update was 3 years ago, add to that by following the official documentation you could use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) and take advantage of [`async` `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) feature, which is the current modern method to handle asynchronous code*.

**That might be an appointed perspective.*

Comment: thanks for your valuable response I will check  official documentation.  is there any way create two separate function.

Comment: You can create the function in a separate module/file, and then import it and make the function call inside the callback.

Comment: after follow your suggestion it has been working smoothly  . check the code, if need any improvement in the code  please guide me . again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Ghassan Maslamani after follow your suggestion it has been working smoothly  . check the code, if need any improvement in the code  please guide me . again thanks.

```
    // get user ip
    const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress;
    // location details through Api call
    const url = `http://api.ipstack.com/${ip}?access_key=${process.env.IPSTACK}`;
    async function locationInfo() {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get(url);
            const data = await result.data;
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const locInfo = await locationInfo();
    // City name
    const location = `${locInfo.city},${locInfo.country_name}`;
    // zip code
    const { zip } = locInfo;
```

Comment: Looks good form the first glance, I would just note about `localInfo`, when error is thrown in the `locationIfo` function, the value of  `localInfo` will be undefined, hence in the `catch` you are not returning anything....  that being said the next line you are getting `localInfo.city`, would throw the error as: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined...etc